# CppUTest not working

Tags: c, unit-testing, tdd

I am trying to rewrite some legacy C code and would like to have some tests in place before actually starting the rewrite. FOr this I took a look at CppUTest and tried a sample application consisting of a header file `chrtostr.h`, an implementation file `chrtostr.c` and a test file called `test_chrtostr.c` which contents is listed bellow:

```
#include <CppUTest/CommandLineTestRunner.h>

#include "chrtostr.h"

TEST_GROUP(chrtostr)
{
}

TEST(chrtostr, test_chrtostr)
{
  CHECK_EQUAL(chrtostr('n'), "sfsdfds");
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
  return CommandLineTestRunner::RunAllTests(ac, av);
}
```

And the corresponding `Makefile.am`:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign

CPPUTEST_HOME = ./cpputest
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -I$(CPPUTEST_HOME)/include
LDFLAGS = -L$(CPPUTEST_HOME)/lib -lCppUTest

bin_PROGRAMS = chrtostr test_chrtostr
chrtostr_SOURCES = chrtostr.c chrtostr.h main.c
test_chrtostr_SOURCES = test_chrtostr.c
```

The issue is that each time I try to run `make` I get the following traceback which doesn't actually help me too much:  http://pastebin.com/BK9ts3vk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That test driver is written in C++. You'll need to compile that as C++, so rename your file to .cpp and make sure `g++` is called to drive the compile/link (rather than `gcc`).

Comment: Grr, then why do they advocate it as a C and C++ unit test framework? Thanks Mat!

Comment: Yeah, but if I have pure C code that I want to compile *only* with gcc and not g++, then it's a pain. C and C++ are not the same language.

Comment: you can (and **should**) continue to build your C code as C with `gcc`. Only the testcase driver needs to be C++.

Answer (score 7):

You should probably start by getting one of the demos going. You could see how CppUTest is intended to be used with C.  My book, Test-Driven Development for Embedded C, will help you get started too.  The first few chapters use a C-Only test harness. Later examples use CppUTest (I'm one of the authors of CppUTest). I also describe the advantages of a C++ test harness for C.

James

p.s. - for more information on CppUTest, look at CppUTest.org

Comment: BTW: CppUTest has its own makefile. So the easiest way to build it is to run make from it's root.  Then go look at examples.

Comment: There's also a problem when using a C++ test harness for C: if you have to set up lots of state before the actual test runs (on setup()), you'll have to do it in C++, am I right? Thanks for the pointers also.

Comment: You can do the setup in C.  In another comment on this page I mention that c references from C++ must be declared in an extern "C" block.

Comment: Oops... I did not edit that last comment quick enough.  Here is the edited copy:  You can do the setup in C that is in a C++ file.  In another comment on this page I mention that C references from C++ must be declared in an `extern "C"` block.  Fakes and stubs can be done in C or C++. Why I like a C++ test harness for C is that test cases are automatically installed.  Unity is a good tool if you are restricted to C. It generates a test runner using ruby scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking at this again. There were a few problems with your code. C++ errors don't always help clear them up.

I added comment before the things i fixed.

```
#include "CppUTest/TestHarness.h"

//The test file is c++. YOu have to tell it when you are linking to C code
extern "C"
{
#include "chrtostr.h"
}

//A test group needs to have a ';' after it. Under the hood, this macro 
//create a base class for the test cases of the same name
TEST_GROUP(Chrtostr)
{
};

//CHECK_EQUAL uses ==. STRCMP_EQUAL actually compares c-strings
TEST(Chrtostr, wrong)
{
  STRCMP_EQUAL(chrtostr('n'), "sfsdfds");
}
```

Comment: Thanks James for the comments. The truth is I haven't yet made any action - the project I want to refactor has a lot of interaction with the filesystem and I am considering git's approach of testing, that is a TAP-based framework. Using CppUTest would mean a lot of C++ setup code in order to get the tests started. I am still trying to put things in balance and figure out the best course of action. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the "HelloWorld" example in CppUTest is undocumented and while the Appendix in "Test Driven Development for Embedded C" lists only 11 condition checks, I am finding that there are a lot more undocumented helper functions (all pretty much undocumented).  I wouldn't recommend CppuTest unless you are trying to understand the concepts of TDD.

I would look for more of a commercial product or you are going to pick up a lot of bad TDD habits or get really frustrated and just move on.

Comment: do you have any recommendations on commercial products?